# How to find out the URL of enabled theme(s)?

Tags: php

I've done some research, but can't find a solution.

I want the URL or my themes. For example:

```
example.com/atheme
example.com/btheme
example.com/ctheme
```

This is to make a drop down so anonymous users can view different themes, I have a multiside and it's a monumental headache with pluggins...so thinking of doing this manually...

My goal is to have users view different themes so they can choose what theme they want their website to be built upon.

I've seen something about it here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/

I have attempted to paste the code in a post with PHP insert pluggin:

```
   [insert_php]bloginfo ( string $show = '' ) [/insert_php]
```

But not working, how can I do this?

Comment: maybe you should explain better the context of the question. there is no such thing as a url of a theme, just url of theme files, so it sounds like you have some misconception about how themes actually work and being activated

Comment: "url of theme files" then! I want users to be able to select a theme, and that would be based on URL, but the URL doesn't show, I thought maybe it's hidden?

Comment: That you want a user to select a theme is understood. The missing part is what for. You should edit your question and fully explain what you are trying to do if you want a good answer.

Comment: Do you mean select a theme for a new network site that they're about to create, or view the current site with a theme override, or something else? Can't you use the existing Admin site code to do this! It must browse to the blog with a theme override in query string params I'd guess.

Comment: To Mark Kaplun: I added this to the post : "My goal is to have users view different themes so they can choose what theme they want their website to be built upon."

Comment: The URL of your themes will be http://example.com/wp-content/themes/example-theme - assuming you haven't changed the wp-content directory name to something else. But I'm also unsure if this is what you want...

Comment: Hi Tim, tried that at "http://localhost/wp_testing/wp-content/themes/a1" not working....I want users to choose themes from front end drop down. Not sure why nobody can understand....

Answer (score 0):

Before Activation you can't able to get the theme url.

Here it's the functions that you can get the current / enabled theme url.

```
get_template_directory_uri();
```

Comment: THanks, but where do I put this code? And how? I what file, in a post as text?

Comment: Can anybody tell me where to put "get_template_directory_uri();" ?